# OCaml Encapsulation

Tags: oop, ocaml, encapsulation

I'm facing a problem and studying the OCaml documentation did not enable me to find a satisfying solution yet.

The following snippet illustrates my problem:

```
class A = object (self)
    (* this should not be overwrittable in subclass B, but callable
       on objects of type B!
    *)
    method dangerous_one input = 
        (do dangerous stuff...)
        let safe_output = safe_dangerous_one input in
        (... more dangerous things done with safe_output ...)

    (* This is safe, should be overwrittable and callable in subclass *)
    method safe_dangerous_one input = (...)
end

class B = object(self) inherit A as super
    method! safe_dangerous_one input = (* subclass behaviour ... *)
end
```

To sum up the snippet: class A is base class to subclass B. 
It has a dangerous method that is complex and has some dark corners I don't want client code to have to deal with. 
In fact, I want to prohibit subclasses from overwriting method "dangerous_one".

Instead, they should overwrite the function "safe_dangerous_one".

Furthermore, it should be possible to CALL "b#dangerous_one" where "b : B" which uses the (new) definition of the "safe_dangerous"-parts as specified in class B.

My dilemma appears to be: if I simply make method "dangerous_one" private, nothing keeps the client code in class B from overwriting it, potentially even making it public.

If I hide its implementation from the signature, it can not be overwritten anymore, but I cannot call "b#dangerous_one" anymore - the code becomes inaccessible to calls also.

Is there any way to achieve what I aim to do?

Best,
Nablezen

Answer (score 2):

> If I hide its implementation from the signature, it can not be overwritten anymore, but I cannot call "b#dangerous_one" anymore - the code becomes inaccessible to calls also.

You can, you just need to make it `private`, you can't hide `public` methods:

```
  class type safe = object
    method safe_dangerous_one : in_channel -> int
  end

  class a : safe = object (self)
    method private dangerous_one input = input_binary_int input
    method safe_dangerous_one input =
      max 255 (self#dangerous_one input)
  end

  class b parameters = object(self)
    inherit a parameters as super
    method! safe_dangerous_one input =
      super#safe_dangerous_one input + 1
  end
```

If you want `unsafe` method to be accessible, but not overridable, then just re-publish it at another name (kind of [NVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern)):

```
  class type safe = object
    method unsafe_dangerous_one : in_channel -> int
    method safe_dangerous_one : in_channel -> int
  end

  class a : safe = object (self)
    method private dangerous_one input = input_binary_int input
    method unsafe_dangerous_one input = self#dangerous_one input
    method safe_dangerous_one input =
      max 255 (self#dangerous_one input)
  end

  class b = object(self)
    inherit a as super
    method! safe_dangerous_one input =
      super#safe_dangerous_one input + 1
  end
```

And a piece of free advice. In other languages, classes and methods are used as a tool for structuring programs, because they have no better tools. In OCaml you have first class functions, records, structures, etc. So it is better to use a proper tool for at each situation. When you design a class, you should understand, that the `method` by its original definition (not spoiled by C++/Java/Python/etc) is something overridable. A method is an operation that has an implementation that varies across some genera. So, if you define something as a method, and then trying hard to prevent people from overriding it, then chances are high that you're doing something wrong. If you don't want it to be overridable, then just don't define it as a method at all. In your case you should put `dangerous_one` operation into a let-bound function. You can bound it in the context of the class, so that you will have an access to all parameters, or you can bind it on a toplevel, the choice is yours:

```
  class a parameters =
    let dangerous_one input = input_binary_int input in
    object (self)
      method safe_dangerous_one input =
        max 255 (dangerous_one input)
    end

  class b = object(self)
    inherit a as super
    method! safe_dangerous_one input =
      super#safe_dangerous_one input + 1
  end
```

Also, a very good source of documentation about OCaml class system is [Jason Hickey's Introduction to Objective Caml](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs134/cs134b/book.pdf). It is slightly outdated, but is still very good.

Comment: "You can, you just need to make it private, you can't hide public methods"
Well, yeah, I gues what I meant is that I have to make it private and when it is private the method cannot be called on objects anymore..e.g. "b#unsafe_dangerous" won't work because unsafe method is private now.

Comment: sure, then make it private and republish at another name, as I suggested at the second example.